# Changing LiveData in Activity doesn't notify observer in child Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm trying to update LiveData object in activity that hosts a fragment and then I want to update the fragment's UI after observing it. The problem is the fragment's ui only updates when fragment is restarted. What can I do to achievie real-time update of Ui in fragment every time the data changes in activity?

// Activity code:

```
   transactionViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, providerFactory).get(TransactionViewModel.class);  
transactionViewModel.getUserValues();
```

/// Fragment:

```
    transactionViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity(), providerFactory).get(TransactionViewModel.class); 
viewModel.userValues.observe(getActivity(), userValues -> {  if(userValues.data != null){}//update the ui }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achievie "real-time update of Ui" i sugesst using [data-binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding).

In your code, I think you are observing a deferent reference of viewModel.

Try observing after casting your activity(am using kotlin here):

```
        val myActivity = (requireActivity() as MainActivity)
        myActivity.transactionViewModel.viewModel.userValues.observe(getActivity(), userValues -> { 
        if(userValues.data != null){}//update the ui }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment code

> ```
> transactionViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity(), providerFactory).get(TransactionViewModel.class); 
>
> viewModel.userValues.observe(getActivity(), userValues -> {  
>    if(userValues.data != null) {
>        //update the UI 
>    }
> }
> ```

Should be

```
transactionViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity(), providerFactory).get(TransactionViewModel.class); 

// this goes in onViewCreated
viewModel.userValues.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, userValues -> {  
    if(userValues.data != null){
         //update the ui
    }
}
```